# retrieve many data in the foreign key(one to many relationship) using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have foreign key(one to many relationship) and I want to view all that come from id=5(for example) but when calling it, it will loop with that same data and not another data that I save. Here is the picture of database and my foreign key is Id  [image: database]

Here is picture of the problem, it will loop again with that data and not other data for example is Id=5. [image: view the problem]

Here is my model:

```html
    function get_row( $Id) {
        $this->db->where('Id',$Id);
        return $this->db->get('certificatesawardsreceived')->row();

 }
```

Here is my controller:

```html
function goanotherlinkz($Id){
 $row=$this->model_adminlogin->get_row($Id);
           $data['r']=$row;
          
            $this->load->view('CertificatesandAwards', $data);
            
            
        
        
    }
```

and my view:

```
                <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Certificates and Awards</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">



            <?php 

foreach ($r as $row)
{

            ?>
            <input  class="input-lg  text-capitalize" type="hidden" name="Id" placeholder="<?php echo $r->Id  ?>"   readonly=""> 
            <input class="input-lg  text-capitalize"   type="text" name="AwardsReceived" placeholder="Certificates/Awards Received" value="<?php echo $r->Certificates ?>" >

            <input class="input-lg text-capitalize"  type="text" name="Year" placeholder="Year" value="<?php echo $r->Year?>">
            <input class="input-lg  text-capitalize"   type="text" name="Place" placeholder="Place" value="<?php echo $r->Place ?>">
            <?php }?>


      <div class="modal-footer"> 


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button> 
       </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: anybody can help me?

Comment: pls can somebody help me

Comment: anyone can answer me?

Comment: thank you to all, I already got it thank you